# Using derivative to find acceleration

Tags: calculus

Any help with the below question would be appreciated - I have a mental blank at the moment!

A car, initially travelling at the speed $100 \text{ km/hr } (A)$, slows down according to the formula $L(t)=At-Bt^2$ where $L$ is the distance traveled, $t$ is the time, and $B=90 \text{ km/hr}^2$. Using the derivative, find the moment when the car speed becomes $10 \text{ km/hr}$. Find the acceleration of the car at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the first part:$$V(t)=\frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}(At-Bt^2) A - 2Bt=(100)-2(90)t=100-180t$$

Set $v(t)=10$, that is, $$100-180t=10$$ and solve for $t$.

For the second part, 
$$a(t) = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}(A-2Bt)=-2B=-2(90)=-180 \text{km/hr}^2$$